# Do Campaign Goals impact ads directly or they are a set of recommendations?

Tags: google-ads

Based on this article from Google: https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7450050?hl=en

I get the feeling that choosing a campaign goal is a recommendation.

Is it really so?

For example, I had a Search Campaign which had the following:

Campaign Goal:

Website Traffic

Bidding Strategy:

Maximize Clicks

Once I started uploading conversions to Google Ads, Google recommended me to switch the bidding strategy to Maximize Conversions. I accepted the recommendation.

Should I change the Campaign Goal too or it is just a set of recommendations?

My campaign is a search campaign with a Landing Page that contains affiliate links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Campaign Goal is a feature to make it easier for users to become better acquainted with how the campaign set up works and to arrive and typical and recommended set up paradigms.

When you select your Campaign Goal, Google will then highlight features or settings that are determined by Google to work well with that goal. As you become more advanced in your usage of Google Ads you may choose to ignore this process in the future.

*"Should I change the Campaign Goal too or it is just a set of recommendations?"*

It is just a set of recommendations that Google Provides based on limited understand of what you are trying to achieve and determined based on what Google has seen thousands of other people have done. Google just wants to be helpful. You can forge your own path though!